# Does WebLogic 8.1 support Sun JDK 1.5?

Tags: java, migration, weblogic

I am running my applation with Java 1.4.2 version. Now i am migrating to Java 1.5. When I am running my app with new class files it is showing unsupported class version error. How can I change WebLogic server 8.1 SP6 to accept Java 1.5? Is this possible?

Comment: Are you saying the same code (class files) ran on 1.4.2, but no longer on 1.5? That should not happen. Did you re-compile for JDK 6?

Comment: Are you talking about Java 5 or Java 6? Question and title conflict (but answer is likely the same).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Oracle WebLogic 8.1 supported configurations](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13196_01/platform/suppconfigs/configs81/81_over/overview.html), WebLogic 8.1 does not support Java 1.5. It might or might not work, but it is not recommended to try it in a production environment. If you search around, you will see that a lot of people had a lot of assorted problems while trying to use WebLogic 8.1 in conjunction with Java 1.5.

The best path would be trying to migrate to WebLogic 9 or newer, unless it has a prohibitive cost to your team. If that is not possible, it looks like you will have to stick with Java 1.4.2, unfortunately.